# Rules in .gitignore

Tags: git

**1.**
I add this in my .gitignore:

```
temp/cache/
!temp/cache/.htaccess
```

But it still skip (dont commit) everything in *cache* dir including *.htaccess*.

How fix it?

**2.**
Is ok that I commit my .gitignore on github?

Comment: `git` deletes nothing itself. What do you mean? What have you done thus `git` comes to the conclusion to delete _anything_?

Comment: Sorry delete is bad word. I mean skip. -> Update first post ;)

Comment: Yes it's recommended to add the ignore file to **git**.  GitHub is not Git. It's a service that provides support for Git.

Answer (score 0):

yes you do commit and push your .gitignore to your github. It just ignores any changes you made to those files.

e.g.

.gitignore file

```
*~   
/application/config/config.ini
```

this will ignore any changes made to config.ini